# How can I use the same test server configuration for every Ktor test?

Tags: kotlin, dagger-2, ktor, ktor-client

Not sure if this is a limitation of my understanding of the Ktor testing framework, Kotlin or both, but I'd like to use the same Ktor server configuration for every one of my tests.  In all the examples I've seen, the same setup lines for environment, application, etc are repeated in each test.  I'd like to avoid doing that.

What I did was create a new testApp function to do all of my server configuration and then invoke the lambda which is passed to it.  However, when I do this, it seems like none of the configuration code gets called and the invoke function is called immediately.

Of particular concern is that it doesn't seem like the call to inject my BaseTest class with its Dagger dependencies is triggering before my test runs so I end up with calls to lateinit vars that are never initialized.

Here's my BaseTest class that I'm using as a base class for all my tests:

```
open class BaseTest {

    @Inject lateinit var mongoQueries: MongoDbQueries
    @Inject lateinit var jwtTokenGenerator: JwtTokenGenerator

    @Before
    fun setup() {
        MongoTestClient.init()
    }

    lateinit var myClient: HttpClient

    protected fun testApp(block: suspend () -> Unit) = testApplication {
        environment {
            config = MapApplicationConfig().apply {
                put("ktor.deployment.test", "true")
                put("ktor.deployment.port", "8080")
                put("ktor.deployment.mongo_url", "mongodb://localhost")
                put("ktor.deployment.server_environment", "development")
            }
        }

        myClient = createClient {
            install(ContentNegotiation) {
                jackson {
                    defaultConfig()
                }
            }
        }

        application {
            appInjector = DaggerTestApplicationComponent
                .builder()
                .environment(environment)
                .configurationModule(ConfigurationModule(environment))
                .loggingModule(LoggingModule(environment))
                .build()

            (appInjector as TestApplicationComponent).inject(this@BaseTest)

            configureRouting()
            configureSecurity()
            configureSerialization()
        }

        block.invoke()
    }


    @After
    fun tearDown() {
        MongoTestClient.shutdown()
    }
}
```

And then here's an example of one of my tests which extends the base class:

```
class GetUsersControllerTest : BaseTest() {

    companion object {
        const val ROUTE = "/api/v1/users"
    }

    @Test
    fun `Successfully receive list of users of page of users`() = testApp {
        //Add users
        for (i in 0 .. 30) {
            mongoQueries.insertUser(MongoUser(i, randomString(10), randomString(10)))
        }

        val response = myClient.get(ROUTE) {
            contentType(ContentType.Application.Json)
        }

        assertEquals(HttpStatusCode.OK, response.status)

        val list = response.body<List<MongoUser>>()

        assertEquals(BasePagedResultController.DEFAULT_PAGE_SIZE, list.size)
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: The `testApplication` function lazily starts the server when the first request is made so that's why you may have problems with the initialization of your `lateinit` properties. You can create an instance of `TestApplicationEngine` to manage the server's lifecycle. Here is the gist with an example https://gist.github.com/Stexxe/87b6a4985ceda80e1444208cb64826c4.

Comment: @AlekseiTirman thanks!  I think that was a huge piece that I was missing.  I think this solves my dependency injection issue.  Now I have a separate issue with the way I'm handling connections to my test instance of MongoDB.  I don't have this completely solved yet but I'm much closer thanks to your gist!

Comment: @AlekseiTirman You should add this gist as answer here. :)